# How to select a record based on a date which is saved as a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, datetime

The `Bill_Date` is saved as a string in the database. Now I want to select the records based on this `Bill_Date`. So I input two dates ie. `fromDate` and `toDate` (which are also in string).

All the date values use the U.S. format `mm/dd/yyyy` (e.g. `11/28/2011`).

So how will be the query?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz...Bill_Date is saved as 11/28/2011 and the fromDate and toDate are also in this form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your life will be much easier (and the query much faster) if everything was a datetime.

The query (as it stands) would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, BILL_Date, 101)
BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @fromDate, 101) AND CONVERT(datetime, @toDate, 101)
```

`CONVERT` is detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the Strings are in the format YYYY-MM-DD (or any other format, where the dates would be chronologically ordered if you sort by the string) you can use between:

```
select * from table where Bill_date between fromDate and toDate
```

If a different date format is used you need to parse the strings and create dates, either in c# or in sql. In Oracle you would use TO_DATE, i assume there is something similar in SQL server.